# How to parse like count value by query in iphone

Tags: objective-c, facebook-fql

I am using FQL. And here is my code which is fethcing message from stream table.

```
 NSString *fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT actor_id, message,likes FROM stream WHERE source_id = %lld  ORDER BY likes limit 50",_session.uid]
```

And I am getting result like below.

```
{
    "actor_id" = 100002464401210;
    likes =         {
        "can_like" = 1;
        count = 2;
        friends =  (
            {
                uid = 10000215363608;
            }
        );
        href = "http://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=likes&id=106536123438461";
        sample =             (
        );
        "user_likes" = 1;
    };
    message = "hello wall testing..";
},
    {
    "actor_id" = 10000223601210;
    likes =         {
        "can_like" = 1;
        count = 0;
        friends =             (
        );
        href = "http://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=likes&id=108123469280566";
        sample =             (
        );
        "user_likes" = 0;
    };
    message = "New integration";
},
```

I want to sort my query like most liked post will be on top.
How will I modify my query to show most liked on top.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try DESC in your query?

Comment: @Muhammad, I want to sort by "count" value and this is inside of likes array for each record. It means one record is consisting a record which is also a array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified the response format as  JSON .That' why you are getting response in JSON format.

See below blog post to parse you response.

[Tutorial: JSON Over HTTP On The iPhone](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/)

[iPhone JSON Flickr Tutorial – Part 1](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html)

Comment: I am usning FQL. NSString *fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT actor_id, message,likes FROM stream WHERE source_id = %lld  ORDER BY likes limit 50",_session.uid];
    
    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
    [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];

Comment: I am getting my result in this function - (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {  .... } . This is returning data as JSON format but I am asking if we will write query to filter for exact condition, it will return only those part of data right ?